# NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through Agile Web Development with ruby on rails. While running a test, I get the following:

```
Error: LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_update_line_item:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'product_id' for nil:NilClass
        test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:LineItemsControllerTest>
```

Here is my test file

```
require 'test_helper'

class LineItemsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should create line_item" do 
    assert_difference('LineItem.count') do 
        post :create, product_id: products(:ruby).id 
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:line_item).cart)
  end

test "should update line_item" do
  patch :update, id: @line_item, line_item: { product_id: @line_item.product_id }
  assert_redirected_to line_item_path(assigns(:line_item))
end

end
```

Could someone kindly explain why I get a NoMethodError: undefined method while the book says it should be fine?

Thank you!

Update 1

As per Boltz0r's comment below, here are my create and update methods. I tried comparing what I have versus what is in the book and can't seem to find the problem.

```
def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: your `@line_item` is not initialized anywhere and so it's `nil`. It should probably get initialized in before block. Logically you update something that already exists, so to test update you should create something you are going to update.

Comment: `@line_item` is not initialized inside test block, that's why it returns `nil`

Comment: you should initialize `@line_item` inside before block

Comment: I see some problems with your code here:

product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) should be (at)product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

(at)line_item = (at)cart.add_product((at)product.id)

and make some tests... do some flash[:notice] after line_item.save to see if he's actually saving. Get sqlitebrowser and open the database to see if you're getting actual data on the database.

Comment: @Boltz0r Thank you for your response. I got sqlitebrowser as you suggested and I am getting data into the database.

Comment: show me the view where you update line_items

Comment: @yefrem Thank you. I found out how to initialise line_item

Comment: @Boltz0r do you mean the view file?

Comment: you already solved the problem it's ok :) nevermind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112888/discussion-between-salamit-and-boltz0r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the actual example from the book so will now post the answer so maybe somebody else could see it. If you going to test is `update` operation you should have something to update first. That's why the test from the book and any other real-life one has `setup` method to pre-create test item:

```
setup do
  @line_item = line_items(:one)
end
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I am a beginner at this and would like some advice as to what else to study to improve my understanding of Rails. Since you went through the book can you advice me on what material you studied afterwards?

Comment: @Salamit Not sure if my advice would be relevant as I switched to Ruby after some years of PHP. I started with some guides and tutorials, including Rails official ones, then took the book as my knowledge seemed to be a bit fragmented. I can suggest you to also check out that guides, then try to build your own app following best practices you see in the book (like TDD). After that decide according to what your general goal is (why you started all this Ruby/Rails stuff).

Comment: @Salamit also make sure you know learn Ruby itself on some decent level. As RoR is kind of default framework, many folks start their Ruby way with RoR. It's not bad as can give you a feeling of real-life examples and apps but don't forget to learn Ruby and it's cool meta-programming tricks.

Comment: @Salamit also regarding the question, thing is that according to TDD principles every test is run in it's isolated environment, so if you create a record in `create` test it won't appear when you run `update` test, that's why you have to use `setup` to prepare test data.

Answer (score 1):

What that error means is that in here:

```
patch :update, id: (at)line_item, line_item: { product_id: (at)line_item.product_id }
```

the (at)line_item is nil. so it means you probably have an error either on the create method or maybe in the update method (you are not getting the right line_item)

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. I have updated my post with my create and update methods. Could you take a look at it? Thanks a lot!